# Vue.js Force computed properties to recompute?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Here is my component's computed property:

```
methods: {
  addFavoritePlace(place_id) {
    axios.post('/api/add-favorite-place', { place_id: place_id })
      .then(response => {
        // I need here force command.
      });
  },
},

computed: {
  filteredPlaces: function () {
    var is_open;

    if (this.showOpened) {
      is_open = 'open'
    } else {
      is_open = 'close'
    }

    return this.singlePlaces.filter((j) => {
        return j.name.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase();
    });
  }
}
```

And my markup:

```html
<span @click="addFavoritePlace(place.id)" class="favorite-btn active" v-if="place.is_favorited == true">
  <i class="icon-heart"></i>
</span>

<span @click="addFavoritePlace(place.id)" class="favorite-btn" v-else>
  <i class="icon-heart"></i>
</span>
```

I need to call the filtering function inside computed again.
To activate the Favorite button.

Comment: You're not supposed to "recompute" the property, since it will do it on it's own when one of the data involve will change.
In my opinion, you'll just have to update the data inside your original list, `this.singlePlaces`.

Comment: I tried this.But instead of updating the data, it is added again.

Comment: Did yo update the element after finding the index or did you just pushed a new entry ?

Comment: Updated data in database.But it has re-added the state of not updated.

Comment: I meant "updated the element in Vue.js". Your `post` should return the updated value, just assign it to the array at the same index and your computed will update itself.

Comment: Keep in mind that Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Answer (score 46):

If you want to **force a computed property to update** and recalculate it's value, you can simply *use a data property and just mention that property in the computed function* (you don't have to use it, just being there is enough), and then change that data property; This will force the computed value to update.

Here is the code:

```js
data() {
  return {
    refreshKey: 0,
    // ...
  }
},
computed: {
  myComputedValue() {
    // just mentioning refreshKey
    this.refreshKey;

    // rest of the function that actualy do the calculations and returns a value
  },
},
methods: {
  myMethod() {
    // the next line would force myComputedValue to update
    this.refreshKey++;

    // the rest of my method
  },
},
```

Comment: It is better to use a number and increment it, instead of a boolean.  In your case, if `myMethod` is called twice in the same tick, the value will not change and the computed will not be re-evaluated.

Comment: @StevenSpungin you are absolutely right, thank you, I'll update the answer

Comment: Great hack! Fixed my bug

Comment: This is great while it is working. But I assume there must be a more recommended way to do this. There are edge cases where we need `cache` feature of `computed properties`, while having ability to force re-compute it, i.e using `computed` to store element HTML, where changes are not detected

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to force a computed value to update. A computed property will always be recomputed automatically if a needed value is changed.

So, in your case, you will need to change `singlePlaces` and `filteredPlaces` will automatically be updated.

There is a thing to note about Array and Object reactivity as seen in the doc (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays).

In your example, you did not include the code when adding a favorite place, but you will probably need to do something like this:

```
Vue.set(this.singlePlaces, indexOfItem, updatedItem)
```

Comment: I was going to ask: what if that value is set based on a value in the localStorage, but it seems I can do curlies around localStorage.getItem and it updates.

Comment: This is the correct answer to use Vue responsivity as it works without hacks

Comment: @HerbertVan-Vliet could you please explain your comment? I'm using sessionStorage and apparently my computed property is not re-computed after set()

Comment: @Witold: sorry, can't find where I did that. I likely upgraded at some point to get from localStorage on demand. But what does using {sessionStorage} give you?

Comment: @HerbertVan-Vliet You mean like this? `{sessionStorage}.getItem(`
This leads to an error 
`{(intermediate value)}.getItem is not a function`
Don't mind, I get along with an refresh-data-item. I was only curious.

Comment: Likely it was something like {sessionStorage.getItem('something')} but unsure now, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, instead of your markup you could save two times less events handling, two times less DOM nodes creation and two times less recompute and redraw just by toggling the class. Also I'm not sure if invoking a function inside @click event wouldn't fire this function immediately and would just in case wrap it into anonymous function. Also, notice that instead of `place.id` I am passing whole `place` object reference to `addFavoritePlace`:

```
<span
    @click="() => addFavoritePlace(place)"
    class="favorite-btn"
    :class="{active: place.is_favorited}">
        <i class="icon-heart"></i>
</span>
```

Second of all, part of `filteredPlaces` code does not have sense as you are setting variable that is not used elsewhere nor returned, so garbage collector will kill it immediately anyway. Instead you could just go with:

```
computed: {
  filteredPlaces () {
    const search = this.search.toLowerCase()
    return this.singlePlaces.filter((p) => {
        return p.name.toLowerCase().includes(search)
    });
  }
}
```

And at last, you can just update `singlePlaces` items and they will automatically affect filteredPlaces, no need to do anything special, in case you don't have is_favorited property in every `place` you can `map` it on init or force Vue to track its updates with `set` method. Also, as I said, I would pass whole `place` reference instead of `id` so we wouldn't have to find this element again in the stack:

```
methods: {
  async addFavoritePlace (place) {
    await axios.post('/api/add-favorite-place', { place_id: place.id })
    this.$set(place, 'is_favorited', true)
  },
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on it, using the composition API:

**useRefreshable.ts**

```
import { ref } from "vue";

export function useRefreshable<T>(getter: () => T): {
  getter(): T;
  refresh(): void;
} {
  const refreshKey = ref(0);

  return {
    getter() {
      refreshKey.value;
      return getter();
    },
    refresh() {
      refreshKey.value++;
    },
  };
}
```

**useRefreshable.test.ts**

```
import { computed, nextTick } from "vue";
import { useRefreshable } from "@/composition/useRefreshable";

describe("useRefreshable", () => {
  test("", async () => {
    let notReactiveValue = 1;

    function getValue() {
      return notReactiveValue;
    }

    const normalComputed = computed(getValue);

    const refreshable = useRefreshable(getValue);
    const refreshableComputed = computed(refreshable.getter);

    expect(normalComputed.value).toEqual(1);
    expect(refreshableComputed.value).toEqual(1);

    notReactiveValue++;
    await nextTick();

    expect(normalComputed.value).toEqual(1);
    expect(refreshableComputed.value).toEqual(1);

    refreshable.refresh();
    await nextTick();

    expect(normalComputed.value).toEqual(1);
    expect(refreshableComputed.value).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

You could wrap this is many different ways, e.g.:

```
import { computed, ComputedRef } from "vue";
import { useRefreshable } from "@/composition/useRefreshable";

export function useRefreshableComputed<T>(getter: () => T): {
  readonly comp: ComputedRef<T>;
  refresh(): void;
} {
  const refreshable = useRefreshable(getter);
  return {
    comp: computed(() => refreshable.getter()),
    refresh: refreshable.refresh,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Vue3

```
const now = computed(()=> new Date())

//manually update
now.effect.run()
```

Comment: It does recalculate, but the display value (`{{ now }}`) is not updated?

Answer (score 0):

This one is a simple solution

```
this._computedWatchers.computedName.run()
```

where `computedName` is the name of desired `computed` item.